# GCP dynamic https proxy/loadbalancer based on variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

Using Google Cloud GCP I would like to achieve this kind of dynamic redirect:

https://my.domain/$variable -> instance from instance group $variable

https://my.domain/instance-group-name -> instance from instance group "instance-group-name"

Is this possible?

I know I could create a LoadBalancer and add UrlMaps dynamically for every path, but adding a new UrlMap takes like 8 minutes to have effect and I need this to be close to instant.

Answer (score 1):

This feature doesn't exists yet. There is something very similar of what you expect in [the serverless neg configuration named URL Mask](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs#using-url-mask). If you can move your workloads to Cloud Run for example, you will be able to leverage of this feature.